# Define preprocessor macro in Xcode target

Tags: ios, xcode, preprocessor

In my code I have some conditionals:

```
#ifndef SOME_FLAG

// ...

#endif
```

In Xcode project, under target->Build settings->preprocessor macros:

I add to both Debug and Release as well as AppStore which I set up earlier a preprocessor macros:
SOME_FLAG

(The DEBUG already has `DEBUG=1 DEBUG=1` set (as one entry?!!) and I addded another entry of SOME_FLAG.

But it did not work for me. The `#ifndef #endif` block still goes in! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you define that variable in .pch file if you use it in all configuration settings?

Comment: And do you mean that your #ifndef block gets compiled every time??

Comment: Isn't this working as intended?  #ifndef means "if not defined", but you defined SOME_FLAG for both Debug and Release builds, so SOME_FLAG IS defined.

Comment: Why not in .pch? Yes I could do that just as well. Maybe it's a better idea. #ifndef gets compiled every time, yes. I want to preserve the code so I can see but I really don't want it to execute. (it's open source code so I want to see what I've changed) @zpasternack: If it IS defined, then it should not go in. But it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can add value to your SOME_FLAG
for Debug, App Store & Release as-

> Debug: SOME_FLAG = 0
>
> Release: SOME_FLAG = 1
>
> App Store: SOME_FLAG = 2

```
#if SOME_FLAG == 0
NSString *appType = @"Debug Build" ;
#elif SOME_FLAG == 1
NSString *appType = @"Release Build" ;
#else
NSString *appType = @"App Store Build" ;
#endif

NSLog(@"My App Build is %@",appType); //My App Build is Release Build
```